# How can I reduce graphics card temperature?

Tags: graphics-cards, pc, cooling, heat-sink, nvidia

I recently (about 2-3 months ago) brought an RTX 3070 MSI Ventus2X OC. It is a dual fan GPU and ran pretty fine at 98-99% usage at 1900MHz and gave the temperature of about 70-75 C sometimes touching 80.

But recently the card has been keeping 90-92 C  at 1600MHz and 70-80% usage due to thermal throttling. My room gets fairly warm during the summers. Even when I switch on air conditioning, it still runs at 86 - 88 C.

The cooling is adequate on the PC. The case is an ATX case (Antec NX210) , there are 3 intake fans and 1 exhaust fans. There is enough space between the graphics card and the bottom of the case to get enough air through.

I wanted to know whether I can cool it further with some software tweaks as I don't want to open the card as it is still in warranty.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to try, First there is a software solution. *MSI Afterburner* is a free program you can download, and it has options to change the fan curve of your GPU. This way you can set the fan to run at 100% at higher temperatures and still have it be quiet when idle.

The same can be done for the fans in the uefi/bios of your system, Some motherboards have the option to use the motherboard temperature or cpu temperature to set fan speed. I personally prefer using the motherboard temperature since that is more indicative of general case temperature in my particular system, though results may vary.

Second. A small hardware check that you can do is to see if all the screws on the back of the cooler are tightened properly. be careful not to over tighten though. carefully check to see if there's one screw with little to no resistance and tighten it a bit.

Lastly when you say the cooling is adequate.. I actually doubt it. the NX210 might have enough fans, but there's a solid front panel with only a tiny gap for air.
I'd suggest removing the front panel to see if this makes a difference. Worst case you could remove it during the summer, and put it back on in winter.

Comment: I have set the GPU fan curve using the MSI Afterburner, there is no difference. As for cooling in the case, the entire side panel where the the intake fans are placed are slitted both sides for air flow, moreover the bottom of the case where the fans are is open. The top of the case also has holes which are covered by a magnetic dust filter. I don't think there are any screws loose as I took out the GPU for a rough wipe down for dust about a month ago. I will try the BIOS with motherboard set for the temperature.

Comment: @RohitKrishnan I'd still sugest trying to pop off the front to see if it makes a difference. From the images that I can see, the air slits are quite thin so those fans need to work pretty hard to get some decent airflow. And since it's usually relatively easy to pop the front of. It's something that I always recommend with those glass front cases.